# How to visualize CGAL resutls with VTK library

Tags: cgal

I am new in this forum.

I have a problem in my project in c++.

I used vtk and Itk and Qt, but the mesh was not perfect so I tried to include CGAL with cmake.

I can do everything using CGAL, but I can't visualize the object created with CGAL. I have tried to export the results (coordinates, vertices, triangles...) to a generic file like xml or txt to be able to read it from vtk and render it.

Please can you help me to find a way to visualize the CGAL operations?

Thank you

Comment: For which data structure of CGAL ?

Comment: Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2
Compile Mesh_2 cgal example and try to renderer the vertices using vtk, I want to be able to design the cgal result in vtk
Is there any way to extract the mesh data to a text file ? thanks

Answer (score -1):

There is a mesh to vtk [converter](http://cgal-discuss.949826.n4.nabble.com/Viewing-CGAL-meshes-in-paraview-td4657296.html) which I used a while ago.